# error C2677: binary '+=' : no global operator found which takes type 'Movie' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a generic class which stores `Movie` objects in an array.
I want to override the `+=` and `-=` operators in order to add or delete an element from the array.

```
template<typename Element>
movieArray<Element>& movieArray<Element>::operator-=(int position)
{
    // some code here...
    return *this;
}

template<typename Element>
void movieArray<Element>::deleteElem(int position)
{
    this->elements -= position;
}
```

The delete part works as expected. However, when I do the same thing for the Add operation:

```
template<typename Element>
movieArray<Element>& movieArray<Element>::operator+=(const Element &elem)
{
    elements[lenght++] = elem;
    return *this;
}

template<typename Element>
void movieArray<Element>::addElem(const Element &elem)
{
    resizeArray();
    this->elements += elem;
}
```

I receive the following error:

> error C2677: binary '+=' : no global operator found which takes type 'Movie' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I am not sure why this is happening.

If I change `Element` to `int`, like I have at the `-=` method, the code is compiled.

Comment: You need to change your title to better reflect the actual question and not a very specific error.  Otherwise you won't get much response. Something like: Error with Specifying Binary += Global Operator.

Comment: Can you show the code snippet in which you instantiate your template ?

Comment: What is `elements` declared as? The error is telling you that the type used for `elements` does not have an `operator+=` implementation that accepts a `Movie` as input.  If you want `addElem()` to invoke your `operator+=` then use `*this += elem;` instead of `this->elements += elem;`  Similar with `deleteElem()`, to invoke your `operator-=`, use `*this -= position;` instead of `this->elements -= position;`.

Comment: In any case, why are you using a fixed array instead of a container like `std::vector` or `std::list`?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. The elements  variable is declared generic as `Element* elements;` under the `friend class GenericIterator<Element>;` class. The below answers helped me solve the issue.  I replaced `this->elements += elem` with `*this += elem`. Now it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
template<typename Element>
movieArray<Element>& movieArray<Element>::operator-=(int position)
{
    // some code here...
    return *this;
}

template<typename Element>
void movieArray<Element>::deleteElem(int position)
{
    *this -= position;
}

template<typename Element>
movieArray<Element>& movieArray<Element>::operator+=(const Element &elem)
{
    resizeArray();
    elements[lenght++] = elem;
    return *this;
}

template<typename Element>
void movieArray<Element>::addElem(const Element &elem)
{
    *this += elem;
}
```

Or this:

```
template<typename Element>
movieArray<Element>& movieArray<Element>::operator-=(int position)
{
    deleteElem(position);
}

template<typename Element>
void movieArray<Element>::deleteElem(int position)
{
    // some code here...
}

template<typename Element>
movieArray<Element>& movieArray<Element>::operator+=(const Element &elem)
{
    addElem(elem);
    return *this;
}

template<typename Element>
void movieArray<Element>::addElem(const Element &elem)
{
    resizeArray();
    elements[lenght++] = elem;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this did the trick: I changed this->elements += elem with *this += elem. Now it works correctly. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

We are guessing a lot since you only posted a little fraction of your code. But perhaps you meant:

```
*this += elem;
```

which would call your class's overloaded `operator+=` function that you showed, instead of:

```
this->elements += elem;
```

which would call `+=` on the member variable `elements`.   You haven't told us what `elements` is , but (based on your symptoms) perhaps it has some type which has `+=` defined for `int` but not for `Element`.

---

NB. Not related to your compilation error, but `resizeArray();` should be inside `operator+=` , otherwise (assuming that this function is necessary to make space in the array) you will overflow your space when someone calls `operator+=` instead of `addElem`.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick: I changed this->elemements += elem with *this += elem. Now it works correctly.